# regarding the ways of removing surrounding background areas during processing the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

The attached image, showed as follows

[image]

It includes some surrounding areas that represents the noise or background introduce while getting the image.

[image]

How to remove this part while processing the image. For instance, when I try to segment the original image, I got the following result, where the background areas are also included.

[image]

Comment: provide an image without annotations.

Comment: What methods did you use for segmentation?

Comment: @Piglet, I have included the original image.

Comment: @ T A,  I used slic method in skimage segments = slic(img, n_segments = numSegments, sigma = 5,compactness=0.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a flood fill starting at the bottom-right corner to fill all pixels less than some *"fuzziness"* distance (in shades of grey terms rather than in geometric distance terms) with black so they all come out to the same class.

Here I do it with **ImageMagick** just in Terminal, and colour using red and blue, rather than black, to show the concept:

```
convert input.jpg -fuzz 15% -fill red -floodfill +1140+760  black  result15.jpg
```

[image]

Or, allowing slightly fewer colours (darker) to match via fuzziness:

```
convert input.jpg -fuzz 10% -fill blue -floodfill +1140+760  black  result10.jpg
```

[image]

You can do this with **OpenCV** in Python, and **Wand** and other tools. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58250864/2836621) showing how to do a floodfill withPIL/Pillow.